# Нужно построить схему (arduino)

Tags: arduino

построить схему и написать программу для счетчика чисел. По нажатию на кнопку происходит прибавление к счетчику. Вывод значения счетчика сделать с помощью 8 светодиодов которые будут отображать чисто в двоичном виде[image] .

Решение:

```
const int knopka = 10; 
const int lampochki[] = {2,3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}; 
int schet = 0; 

void setup() {
  pinMode(knopka, INPUT_PULLUP); 
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    pinMode(lampochki[i], OUTPUT); 
  }
}

void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(knopka) == LOW) { 
    schet++; 
    if (schet > 255) { 
      schet = 0;
    }
    vivodschet(); 
    delay(250); 
  }
}

void vivodschet() {
  int VklVykl[] = {128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1}; 
  int vivod = schet; 
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    if (vivod >= VklVykl[i]) { 
      digitalWrite(lampochki[i], HIGH); 
      vivod -= VklVykl[i]; 
    } else {
      digitalWrite(lampochki[i], LOW); 
    }
  }
}
```

Не знаю, решил как смог. Уверен, что есть решение проще.

Comment: и в чем собственно суть вопроса?

Comment: каким образом это можно реализовать.

Comment: ну, начало у вас уже есть. что остаётся поискать-сделать? 

1. нарисовать кнопочку  инкремента и подключить к ардуино. 

2. так, записать число в pinnuber. и в loop этот фокус не пройдёт, почему? как вариант, вместо loop вам надо поставить анализ нажатия кнопки

3. функция преобразования числа в эквивалент 7 segment indicator, тут представление https://www.electronicwings.com/arduino/7-segment-display-interfacing-with-arduino-uno

вуаля

Comment: еще должна выскочить проблема "дребезга контактов" (contact bounce arduino) https://arduinogetstarted.com/tutorials/arduino-button-debounce

Comment: дребезг уже вылезал, пофиксил дилэем